# resignFirstResponder for UIPicker in UITextField Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview, uitoolbar

I want the UIPickerView to be dismissed (slide out of view) after the done button is clicked on the toolbar. I've linked the UIPickerView as the inputView of the UITextField and set the UIToolbar as the inputAccessoryView of the UIPickerView. However, my function calling resignFirstResponder does not slide the UIPicker out of the view. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //initialization constants
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    let textField = UITextField()
    let pickerData = ["1","2","three"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //pickerview tool bar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44))
        var items = [AnyObject]()
        //making done button
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: Selector(donePressed()))
        items.append(doneButton)
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)


        //creating textfields with a pickerview
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 300)
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        textField.inputView = pickerView
        textField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 55, 100, 35)
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    //adding objs to viewController
    self.view.addSubview(textField)
}

func donePressed() {
    resignFirstResponder()
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

//MARK: Data Sources UIPickerView
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
}

//MARK: Delegates UIPickerView
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    // several optional methods:




func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    textField.text = pickerData[row]
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. Your selector for `donePressed` is declared incorrectly. It should be:

   ```
   let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "donePressed")
   ```
2. You need to call `resignFirstResponder()` on `textField`:

   ```
   func donePressed() {
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
   }
   ```

---

If you have multiple textFields, and you don't want to hardcode the textField in the `resignFirstResponder` call, you can do the following:

1. Make your `ViewController` a `UITextFieldDeletate`:

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
   ```
2. Set the `delegate` property on your `UITextField`:

   ```
   textField.delegate = self
   ```
3. Add a property to your `ViewController` to keep track of the active `UITextField`:

   ```
   var activeTextField:UITextField?
   ```
4. Implement `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and store the active `UITextField`:

   ```
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) { // became first responder
       activeTextField = textField
   }
   ```
5. In `donePressed`, call `resignFirstResponder` on `activeTextField`:

   ```
   func donePressed() {
       activeTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
   }
   ```

Comment: To expand on the 2nd problem, what if I had multiple UITextFields linked with separate UIPickerViews. Is there a way to pass the active textfield through the function donePressed()?